# Required context `routeDepth` was not specified in `RouteHandler`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I've been trying to prototype a React app for a few hours and I got stuck while trying to implement routes. The errors I have are:

```
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `routeDepth` was not specified in `RouteHandler`.
Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in `RouteHandler`.
Warning: owner-based and parent-based contexts differ (values: `undefined` vs `1`) for key (routeDepth) while mounting RouteHandler
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRouteAtDepth' of undefined
```

It's an isomorphic app (rendered on server and client) and apparently everything I read says about **React or React-Router being loaded twice**. But I haven't seen a decent way of solving this problem and what causes it (is it Gulp configuration or just the way React is imported across files?).

Here is what I have:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');

require("babel/register");

var routes = require('./app/routes.js');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
  Router.run(routes, req.path, function(Handler) {
    var html = React.renderToString(React.createElement(Handler));
    var page = res.render(__dirname + '/server/views/index.ejs', {reactOutput: html});
  });
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function(req, res) {
    console.log('Server started');
});

require('./server/routes/routes.js')(app, io);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"><%- reactOutput %></div>
    <script src="/bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js** (that will become **bundle.js** after gulp runs)

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactApp = require('./components/App/ReactApp.js');
var Activity = require('./components/Activity/Activity.js');
var Router = require('react-router');
var routes = require('./routes.js');
var Route = Router.Route;
var Link = Router.Link;

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.getElementById("app"));
});
```

**routes.js**

```
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var Link = Router.Link;

var App = require('./components/App/ReactApp.js');
var ActivitiesList = require('./components/ActivitiesList/ActivitiesList.js');
var Activity = require('./components/Activity/Activity.js');
var Task = require('./components/Task/Task.js');


export default (
  <Route path="/" handler={App}>
    <Route path="/activity" component={Activity}/>
  </Route>
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm replying my own question because I have couple of things I was doing wrong and thought it's worth sharing:

1. For unknown reason, the error that raised this question went away when I changed my ReactApp component's syntax from ES5 to ES6. (I didn't post this file in the question); I don't know if this is browserify requirement, but I ended up changing all my ES5 syntax to ES6 and if you're starting with React, I advise you doing the same as most of the examples are with ES6.
2. In `server.js` my require for the server routes file (`require('./server/routes/routes.js')`) should be before `Router.run`, otherwise all my api requests will be intercepted by React-Router;
3. In `<Route path="/activity" component={Activity} />` I replaced `component` by `handler`.
4. In `routes.js` replace `Router.HashLocation` by `Router.HistoryLocation` if you don't want the hash `#` in your URL.